# krusader custom view matching more than one pattern

Tags: krusader

I one directory I have 100 files, but I only work with 10. is it possible to make custom view that matches many patterns?

for example I want to match files that start with `super`, but also those which start with `extra`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pattern can be entered after space, so it would be

> super extra